# Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+

Tags: android

when I created a new Android Studio project, there was an error named (Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+).

I didn't do anything. I just created this project. What's going on?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmwn1.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is an action below in the console.
You can install the desire dependency by `Install repository and sync project`

Answer (score 0):

Add In to app Gradle file

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```